# Unused warning for UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleBottomMargin

Tags: swift, xcode

I've updated my project into Swift 3 from Swift 2.3.
The Swift compiler warning display "Expression of type 'UIViewAutoresizing' is unused"

```
self.autorisizinMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth]
UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleBottomMargin // Warning
```

Please see the attached screenshot, Thanks!
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKLSt.png)

Comment: Quite obviously because the result of the expression UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleBottomMargin is not used. What do you think it is supposed to do?

Answer (score 3):

The warning is self explanatory. It is telling that you aren't using this value.

A value can be used by assigning it to some variable.

If i'm not mistaken, i think you've mistakenly written `UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleBottomMargin` outside the array.

If this is the case, then it should look something like:
`self.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleBottomMargin]`

Hope this helps!

As suggested @Cœur in the comment below, you may rewrite the above statement as:
`autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth, .flexibleBottomMargin]`

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Kindly accept my answer if you think it was helpful! :)

Comment: I recommend to simplify it to `autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth, .flexibleBottomMargin]`

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3 if you don't capture the return value it will show the warn. In previous swift version No warning would occur when you did not capture what the method returned.

If you don't want to use the return value, you have to explicitly tell the compiler by assigning it to an underscore:

```
    _ = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleBottomMargin
```